# How to re init context menu?

Tags: jquery, contextmenu

The jquery context menu works fine if I assign it first time. But when I re-assign it second time context menu works with previous function.

> Code with first time:

```
$("#26134_x16Fwj2VUp8Sa74").contextMenu("rowContMenu_26134_x16Fwj2VUp8Sa74", 
{bindings: 
        { 'itemQuickEdit_26134_x16Fwj2VUp8Sa74' : function(t) 
                { 
                showQuickEditForm(26134,'x16Fwj2VUp8Sa74'); 
                }
        }
});
```

> Code with second time:

```
$("#26134_x16Fwj2VUp8Sa74").contextMenu("rowContMenu_26134_x16Fwj2VUp8Sa74", 
{bindings: 
        { 'itemQuickEdit_26134_x16Fwj2VUp8Sa74' : function(t) 
                { 
                **showFullEditForm**(26134,'x16Fwj2VUp8Sa74'); 
                }
        }
});
```

So I think it have to be function like re-init. `($.removeData etc...)`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried ?

```
$("#26134_x16Fwj2VUp8Sa74").unbind().contextMenu("rowContMenu_26134_x16Fwj2VUp8Sa74", 
{bindings: 
        { 'itemQuickEdit_26134_x16Fwj2VUp8Sa74' : function(t) 
                { 
                **showFullEditForm**(26134,'x16Fwj2VUp8Sa74'); 
                }
        }
});
```